# How to feed javascript function a variable in a parameter to change?

Tags: javascript, function, svelte

For example, I have this code:

```js
  function verifyContents(fieldInfo, indicator){
    if (fieldInfo === ""){
      indicator = "You didn't enter anything in here";
      return;
    }
    else{
      indicator = "";
    };
  };
```

I want to get fieldInfo, check if it's empty, and change the variable inputted in indicator based on it. I just call it like this:

```js
verifyContents(formContents[0],usernameFieldIndicator);
```

Comment: How you are going to call this function? add possible calling methods to help us get clarity on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a reactive svelte variable just by using `let myVar` so here you don't need to pass the variable as a parameter, just use it directly:

```html
<script>
    let indicator = ""

    function verifyContents(fieldInfo){
      if (fieldInfo === ""){
        indicator = "You didn't enter anything in here";
      }
      else{
        indicator = "";
      };
    };
</script>

<button on:click={() => verifyContents("", indicator)}>verify!</button>
<p>{indicator}</p>
```

Check the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/40dcf075bda649ae8d833b805a75de8d?version=3).